How to download the git folder from Azure DevOps using powershell
I was trying to download the folder from a GIT based repository in Azure DevOps. I was able to download it through the below script.
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PROJECT}/_apis/git/repositories/{RepoNameORRepoID}/items?scopePath=folderpath(e.g. doc/build/html )&download=true&`$format=zip&api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/zip  -OutFile "c://repo.zip"

The above script works perfectly on the machines. The script fails when I try to run this powershell script from Azure DevOps release pipeline. I have created a release pipeline and added a powershell task to download the folder from a GIT based repository.
It fails with error Invoke-RestMethod : Unable to connect to the remote server
Please let me know if any one able to achieve this scenario

is there a reason you are not using git clone? that's like totally what its for.

@Frank Thomas - The git clone was for to clone to entire Repo. At the moment, I was looking to download the specific folder only using powershell.

@Vomit IT - Yes, I have ensure that PAT is correct and works like a charm if I run the powershell script in a wi dows machine. But it gives an error if I run it through Azure devops release pipeline.
